# Error while creating changeset - "DependsOn must be a string or list of strings."

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am using cloudformation to deploy my code. In my yml file I ahve this `DependsOn` attribute for which I am trying to add value as "AppApiv1Stage". I have tried multiple things, everytime it gives different errors not sure what I am doing wrong. In the below code snippet first I added it in double quotes like this:`"AppApiv1Stage"` then it showed error. Again I tried with below code, then it showed me error as "DependsOn must be a string or list of strings"

```
Parameters:
  ApiStageSecondDeploymentName:
    Description: API Stage name to use
    Type: String
    Default: v1
Resources:
 AppAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    DependsOn: AuthFunction
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}
      StageName: !Ref ApiStageSecondDeploymentName          
      Variables:
        LocalTLD: local                                    # Deploys a Dev stage to use for tests and development
      MethodSettings:
        - LoggingLevel: ERROR
          MetricsEnabled: True
          DataTraceEnabled: True
          HttpMethod: '*'
          ResourcePath: '/*'
          ThrottlingBurstLimit: !Ref ApiBurstLimit
          ThrottlingRateLimit: !Ref ApiRateLimit
ApiMapping:
    DependsOn: !Sub AppAPI !Ref ${ApiStageSecondDeploymentName}Stage
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Properties:
      BasePath: !Ref ApiStageSecondDeploymentName
      DomainName:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${CustomDomainStack}-DNSName
      RestApiId: !Ref AppAPI
```

I also tried with Join! but showing error again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> not sure what I am doing wrong

`DependsOn`, as the error says, must be a **string**, or **list of strings**. Not an intrinsic function (Sub, Ref).

What's more, intrinsic functions can be only used in few places in a template, none of which is `DependsOn`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html):

> You can use intrinsic functions **only in specific parts of a template**. Currently, you can use intrinsic functions in resource properties, outputs, metadata attributes, and update policy attributes. You can also use intrinsic functions to conditionally create stack resources.

Comment: Thanks solves one of my queries. 
How do I then add the AppAPIv1Stage in the depends on attribute, since adding it in double quotes does not help either?

Comment: @ShrutiJoshi Can you update the question with what exactly you tried and full error message?

Comment: I was getting Resource not found error, I tried with "AppAPIStage" instead of "AppAPIv1Stage" and it worked fine